# Upgraded Nuke, now I am getting a No module named 'PySide2.QtWebSockets' error

Tags: pip, pyside, pyside2, nuke, qtwebsockets

I'm a VFX artist trying to expand my horizons into coding, so sorry for my noob question.

In Nuke 13 I can load a plugin called NukeServerSocket v1.5 which uses PySide2 just fine. But I updated the application to Nuke 14, it crashes with a

```
No module named 'PySide2.QtWebSockets' error
```

Nuke did switch from python 3.7 to 3.9 between versions.

I can still type in

```
import PySide2
```

into Nuke 14's terminal and it imports fine, but not

```
import PySide2.QtWebSockets
```

I reinstalled PySide2 via pip, but how would I go about installing QtWebSockets for PySide2?

Comment: If you want to use NukeServerSocket along with Nuke 14, you should download the latest version, which is 0.6.0 from GitHub or 1.6 from Nukepedia. This version does not support WebSocket functionality but is compatible with Nuke 14.